# Creating an ASP.net GridView board (without server connection)

Tags: asp.net

I'm going to create a 4-column, 10-line gridview board. I want to make it using a loop. I do not know what to do with the cs code. I am a beginner and I am practicing as an example. Help please.

.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
                            AllowSorting="True" 
                            AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
                            ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound" EmptyDataText="NO">

         <EmptyDataTemplate>No Data</EmptyDataTemplate>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Complete";
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
            var str = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["SomeColumnName"];
        }
```

Comment: If you are a beginner I suggest you learn about MVC rather than webforms

Comment: I added a quick example

Answer (score 0):

Quick Example:

**.aspx code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

**.cs code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Create a datatable as a DataSource of your GridView
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Add columns
        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("Column" + i);
            }
        }

        // Add rows
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add("Data" + i, "Data" + i, "Data" + i, "Data" + i);
        }

        // Bind datatable to gridview
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]